# Recommended way to Schedule a job to run in Azure with an ASP.NET MVC web app?

Tags: azure

We're looking at setting up some sort of Job to go through our system on a schedule and based on criteria, create emails for users. The system is a .Net based MVC web site with an MS SQL database.

It looks like Scheduler would fit, but then I saw the Batch service. What would you recommend?

Answer (score 2):

If you host the ASP.NET MVC application within an Azure Web App, then you could simple implement a Web Job to run on the necessary schedule. With the application hosted in Azure Web App, then this would be the simplest solution to implement.

Comment: I'd definitely go with a web job as Chris suggested. Here's a link to a tutorial: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-get-started/